# Python - User defined Functions

Tags: python, function

I am trying to convert code(that registers a user) to a function, but instead it gives output = None instead of a concatenated string (new_user_name + ", " + new_password). Can anyone enlighten me as to what mistake am I making, the code itself already works when its not a function.

```
def reg_user ():
    
    #Input from the admin to enter the user name and password for the new user
            
    new_user_name = input("Enter new Username: ").strip()
            
    new_password = input("Enter new Password: ").strip()
            
    confirm_new_password = input("Re-enter new Password: ").strip() #Password confirmation
            
    while new_password != confirm_new_password:
                
        print("Password does not match. Ensure you have put the same password")
                
        print()
                
        new_password = input("Enter new Password: ").strip()
                
        confirm_new_password = input("Re-enter new Password: ").strip()
                
        if new_password == confirm_new_password:
                
            return (new_user_name + ", " + new_password)

new_user = reg_user()
print(new_user)

OUTPUT = None

Desired output = eg. (Sanele, 595dasdf)
```

Comment: You have a simple problem that the retuen statement is inside the loop and if the user gives same password first time then that statement is never hit thus it returns default None

Comment: Ow! thank you so much. I cant believe I made such an error, but then again I am new. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a small error with your indentation:

```
def reg_user ():
    
    #Input from the admin to enter the user name and password for the new user
            
    new_user_name = input("Enter new Username: ").strip()
            
    new_password = input("Enter new Password: ").strip()
            
    confirm_new_password = input("Re-enter new Password: ").strip() #Password confirmation
            
    while new_password != confirm_new_password:
                
        print("Password does not match. Ensure you have put the same password")
                
        print()
                
        new_password = input("Enter new Password: ").strip()
                
        confirm_new_password = input("Re-enter new Password: ").strip()
                
                
    return (new_user_name + ", " + new_password) # Has to be one tab less

new_user = reg_user()
print(new_user)

OUTPUT = None

# Desired output = eg. (Sanele, 595dasdf)
```

Comment: the `if new_password == confirm_new_password:` is totally unnecessary as it will always be true as this line is only encountered after the passwords are same

Comment: Very true! I did not notice.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can fix your script simply by reducing the `if` statement identation one level.

However, your code have some bad coding practices, like it is *WET* (you *Write Everything Twice*) instead of keeping it *DRY* (*Don't Repeat Yourself*). Here you have my version:

```
def reg_user ():

    new_user_name = input("Enter new Username: ").strip()
    while True:
        new_password = input("Enter new Password: ").strip()
        confirm_new_password = input("Re-enter new Password: ").strip()
        
        if new_password == confirm_new_password:
            return new_user_name + ", " + new_password
        
        print("Password does not match. Ensure you have put the same password")


new_user = reg_user()
print(new_user)
```

Comment: love this community definitely learning a lot, thank you